# Is it possible to use electron-builder to build windows apps from MacOS?

Tags: electron, electron-builder, electron-packager

I recently got a Mac, as windows can not build a Mac application with apples signing. I was wondering if Mac can, however, build Windows and even Linux apps?

Comment: I'm not familiar with electron-builder but would be useful if you include details of what you already know about it in your question, such as something you tried. There's also a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43507812/how-to-develop-windows-app-on-visual-studio-for-mac) that perhaps could help you provide additional information to your question. By the way, a Windows virtual machine might be an option to consider. Because even if you can build a Windows application on Mac, you'd probably want to run and test it...

Comment: Also, there are several [types of Windows applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/application-management/apps-in-windows-10), so it's useful to be more specific.

Comment: https://www.electron.build/multi-platform-build#build-electron-app-using-docker-on-a-local-machine, this may answer your question.

Comment: Yes, you can build Windows apps. I haven't figured out how to do Windows code signing through `electron builder` so I still take the built .exe over to a Windows machine (actually VMWare running Windows 10 in emulation) to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link posted by [Ameer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10213537/ameer) ([electron.build](https://www.electron.build/multi-platform-build#build-electron-app-using-docker-on-a-local-machine)) explains that Microsoft builds can be made for Windows and Linux inside docker containers. So yes, you should be able to build to both Windows and Linux provided you have docker.